# Method to Print MTJ Matrix to CSV or other text format?

Tags: java, matrix, export-to-csv, mtj

Context: I need to export the MTJ matrix to Python. Seems like exporting to CSV, then reimporting te CSV from Python, is the best.

**How to export a MTJ matrix to CSV?** Is there a method from the library I missed? Or any other way than just doing it by hand?